# Creating A PHP file that will allow users to enter data and then it will added to my database

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a php file which will allow a 'customer' to add information to and when that information is added and submitted, the information should then be added on to my database. However, the after several attempts I cannot get data to be entered into the database.

Here is the code for the user to be able to view for the form...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Payment</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleshoppingcart.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Please Enter The Following Details</p>

   <form method="post" action="outputty.php">
     <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
            <label>Last Name:<input name="lastname" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
            <label>Card Type:<input name="cardtype" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
            <label>Card Number:<input name="cardnumber" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
            <label>Expiry Date:<input name="expiry" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
            <label>Door Number Date:<input name="doornumber" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
            <label>Post Code:<input name="postcode" type="text"/></label>
     </p>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear Entries"/>
     </p>
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is the code for the PHP file that should allow the data to be entered on to the database.

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>NBA Memorabilia | Orders</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleshoppingcart.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Orders</h2>

<?php
     //Connect to database
     $location = "localhost";
     $username = "********";
     $password = "********";
     $database = "db?k1009076";
     $conn=@mysql_connect("$location","$username","$password");
     if (!$conn) die ("Error: Could not connect to database server.");
     @mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die ("Error: Could not open database.");
     extract($_POST);
     if (isset($name))
     {
        //Add new comment to database
        @mysql_query("CREATE TABLE order (name VARCHAR(65),lastname VARCHAR(65),
                     cardtype VARCHAR(8), cardnumber VARCHAR(16),   expiryVARCHAR(4),doornumber VARCHAR(10), postcode VARCHAR(10) )");
        $insert = "INSERT INTO order (name,lastname, cardtype, cardnumber, expiry, doornumber, postcode) 
                   VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$cardtype', '$cardnumber', '$expiry','$doornumber','$postcode')"; 
        @mysql_query($insert) or die ("Could not add data to the table"); 
     }

     //Close connection to server
     @$disconn=mysql_close($conn);
     if (!$disconn) die ("Error: Unable to disconnect from database server.");
  ?>
```

Comment: don't do it, its never a good idea to store card numbers and payment details in your own database. Especially with the code you are writing. its vulnerable to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: Also, don’t leave your MySQL connection details such as username and password when posting code.

Comment: Post the error log of Apache. It will tell you where the error is.

Comment: @user1879688 have you tried doing things one step at a time i.e. remove everything and just verify that you can connect to the database. Try isolating your problem. What you are asking is asking to me saying my car has a problem can you please give me some advise to fix it.

Comment: @NicholasKing yes I have done this. It connects to the database and then it goes to the line of my code where it states @mysql_query($insert) or die ("Could not add data to the table");

Comment: you should sanity check the input before inputting into the database. NEVER trust user input or Database output.

Comment: @NicholasKing Thanks..after entering that strip of code etc I have a error. The error is..Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/k1009076/www/HTML2/outputty.php on line 31
Which is the line of code I just entered

Comment: i think the posts will require ' around them so you either have to escape the ' in each $_POST['var'] or assign the vars to another var such as $name = $_POST['name'] and in the insert use $name

Answer (score 2):

Foremost, storing credit card information is not only a terrifyingly bad idea (especially without any encryption it would seem), but also against the [PCI Security Standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php) which would be a problem if you ever want to actually process these numbers you are storing for very long.

Second, the code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and would put not only your general user's data and transactions at risk, but also their credit card numbers in this scenario.

Please do not build web apps for commerce related reasons if you are not aware of information security best practices and proper coding standards for SQL data and/or financial details of end-users.

But to answer your overall question, you have to pass the $_POST data to your database, e.g. $lastname -> $_POST['lastname'] in your statement. But again, don't just pass that data in, or at least use paramterized queries and some sanity checks using regular expressions or other methods to prevent SQL injection as covered in my previous link.